# VBA Code to check if entry exists in a range for each date in a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need VBA code to check if entry exists in a range for a value against each weekday in a date range

If the value to be searched is in C4 and the date range is in B7 & B9 of workbook A, It should check the range A:E in 'Tracker' worksheet in workbook B (in which the value being searched is in column A and individual dates are in column E), if any of the weekday values in the date range exists in the range A:E then it should return a msgbox.

i.e. if the value in C4 is X and the date range in B7 & B9 is 3/1/2022 & 3/10/2022 it should all 'X' entries in the column A of the range A:E in workbook B and check if corresponding entries for each weekday exists in column E, if it finds even one match it should return a msgbox and exit sub

this is what I have tried.

```
  Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Tracker")
  st = DateValue(wsCopy.Range("B7"))
  myrange1 = wsDest.Range("A:F")
  en = wsCopy.Range("c4")
  
  
  Do While st <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
    If (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(en, myrange1, 5, False) = en) Then
    MsgBox "Leave Request already exists"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    st = st + 1
  Loop
  Loop
```

Comment: What have you tried already? We're not a free code website.

Comment: This what i have tried, but it checks and returns only the first entry in the range 
`Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Tracker")
  myrange1 = wsDest.Range("A:F")
  en = wsCopy.Range("c4")
  
  Do While st <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
    If (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(en, myrange1, 5, False) = st) Then
    MsgBox "Leave Request already exists"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    st = st + 1
  Loop`

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1707340/edit) your question to include this code in readable format.

Comment: Because `st` isn't set as anything, it starts as equivalent to `0`. If the end date is in `B9`, then you're going to check every date between 0 and the end date. This will probably be in the 40,000 - 50,000 range. Is that what you want?

Comment: And exactly what is your problem? You have not actually stated what is going wrong.

Comment: I've edited the code, the problem is that `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(en, myrange1, 1, False)` this code only returns the 'first' match in the column, i need to check 'every' match against the corresponding value in column 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find and findnext was the way to go. I was a bit premature, still learning !!! here is what i did to solve it, basic stuff, i'm sorry for wasting your time!

```
Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("G:\Manager Folder\Test\Leave Tracker Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Tracker")
    
     Set myrange1 = wsDest.Range("A:A") 'to be changed to select current range
     en = wsCopy.Range("c4").Value
     Set st = myrange1.Find(en)
     st1 = wsCopy.Range("B7").Value
     
     If st Is Nothing Then
        Resume
     Else
        Do While st1 <= wsCopy.Range("B9").Value
            If (st.Offset(0, 4) = st1) Then
                MsgBox "Leave Request already exists"
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
                Exit Sub
            End If
            st1 = st1 + 1
            st = myrange1.FindNext(st)
        Loop
     End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I apologize, I'm still an infant here, i've added the code